# SQL JOIN with TOP ID from WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

```
-- t_products
prod_id ... name ... price
--------------------------
1           Prod1    23.2
2           Prod2    11.5
3           Prod3    10.0
4           Prod4    4.43 

-- t_products_lists
list_id ... prod_id ... date_created
1           1           2016-02-01
2           1           2015-31-12
3           3           2015-01-01
4           3           2015-12-01
5           4           2014-02-05
6           4           2012-24-06
7           2           2016-11-10
```

What I need is to get from `t_products_lists` all the rows that have `date_created < 2016-01-01` *(2,3,4,5,6)*.

Now, from those results, I only need the `prod_id` with *the latest* `date_created`, for all groups of duplicated `prod_id`. It will be required to get `name` and `price` from `t_products` and return along with `date_created`.

The result should be:

```
prod_id ... name ... price ... date_created
-------------------------------------------
1           Prod1    23.2      2015-31-12 (the only one before 2016-01-01)
3           Prod3    10.0      2015-12-01 (the latest date)
4           Prod4    4.43      2014-02-05 (the latest date)
```

I am trying to join the tables like this so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(prod.prod_id), prod.name, prod.price, prodlist.date_created 
FROM t_products_lists prodlist 
INNER JOIN t_products prod ON prodlist.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
WHERE prodlist.date_created < CONVERT(DATETIME,'01.01.2016 23:59:59.997',0) 
GROUP BY prod.prod_id, art.name, art.price, prodlist.date_created
```

but now I don't know how could I only get the `prod_id` with the latest date, because with this query it just returns all IDs before *01.01.2016*

Answer (score 1):

USE `MAX( prodlist.date_created)`

```
SELECT prod.prod_id, prod.name, prod.price, MAX( prodlist.date_created) 
FROM t_products_lists prodlist 
INNER JOIN t_products prod ON prodlist.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
WHERE prodlist.date_created < CONVERT(DATETIME,'01.01.2016 23:59:59.997',0) 
GROUP BY prod.prod_id, prod.name, prod.price
```

Answer (score 0):

You will require something similar to the below. Instead of grouping by the date created, put a MAX around it in your select clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(prod.prod_id), prod.name, prod.price, MAX(prodlist.date_created )
FROM t_products_lists prodlist 
INNER JOIN t_products prod 
    ON prodlist.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
    WHERE prodlist.date_created < CONVERT(DATETIME,'01.01.2016 23:59:59.997',0) 
GROUP BY prod.prod_id, art.name, art.price
```

You can read a bit more about MAX at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp